# Using swift and Xcode to connect to a speaker

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var myPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Initialize central manager
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
        
        // Audio
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf:
                                                URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "bell", ofType: "wav")!))
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch{
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        
        // Turned on
        if central.state == CBManagerState.poweredOn {
            print("BLE powered on.")
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }
        
        // Not on, could be different issues
        else {
            print("Something wrong with BLE.")
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String: Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber){
        // Get the peripheral.name
        if let pname = peripheral.name{
            print(pname)
            if pname == "Speaker_Name"{
                // found wanted device so stop
                self.centralManager.stopScan()
                
                // assign it to myperipheral object
                self.myPeripheral = peripheral
                self.myPeripheral.delegate = self
                
                //
                self.centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    // Connected
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        self.myPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        print("Connected")
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func clickBell(_ sender: Any) {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

How does one use swift to connect to a speaker without having to connect to the speaker in Bluetooth settings. My intention once I have this portion of the code working is to allow the app to connect and play the bell noise on multiple speakers. This is the code I have so far and it does not connect to the speaker I want it to, but it is able to connect to other devices such as TVs and my AirPods. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It seems like you are searching for BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) devices. Most speakers are Bluetooth Classic devices

Comment: Do you know how one would connect too Bluetooth Classic Devices through swift?

Comment: Take a look at this sample project: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/using_core_bluetooth_classic

Comment: It is not possible to connect on iOS to Bluetooth Classic (also known as BR/EDR) devices programmatically to do anything else than GATT over BR/EDR, **unless** you're a manufacturer and you incorporate an MFI chip into your accessory and use the ExternalAccessory framework. The sample code above is only to do GATT over BR/EDR (services, characteristics and stuff...). All other Bluetooth profiles management (A2DP for audio for example) is managed by the system.